# create 3 responsive box with background color and Image

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

Hi guys I am using Bootstrap and trying to build 3 grey color boxes with background image at the top and a text at below and button. but I am unable to do this I need your help to make it successful [This is what I am trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kC4SW.jpg)

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                    <div class="media services-wrap wow fadeInDown">
                   <div class="pull-left">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="images/img1.jpeg">
                        </div>
                        <div class="media-body">
                            <h3 class="media-heading">Text 1</h3>
                            <p>CHeck out Button</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with Bootstrap [Custom Content](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#thumbnails-custom-content) as a base instead of the Media object you're currently using. Then just apply the styling you want.

*Note this is based of a specific image size so these rules will need to be adjusted based on the actual image size you end up using.

See working Example Snippet.

```css
.thumbnail.checkout-thumbnail {
  background: #eee;
  border: none;
  max-width: 370px;
  margin: 5px auto;
}
.caption.checkout-caption {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.btn.btn-checkout {
  border-radius: 0;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.btn.btn-orange {
  border: 2px solid orange;
}
.btn.btn-teal {
  border: 2px solid teal;
}
.btn.btn-red {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container text-center">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <div class="thumbnail checkout-thumbnail">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x200" alt="...">
        <div class="caption checkout-caption">
          <h3>House and Land Packages</h3>

          <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-checkout btn-orange" role="button">Check out Button</a> 
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <div class="thumbnail checkout-thumbnail">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x200" alt="...">
        <div class="caption checkout-caption">
          <h3>House and Land Packages</h3>

          <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-checkout btn-teal" role="button">Check out Button</a> 
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <div class="thumbnail checkout-thumbnail">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x200" alt="...">
        <div class="caption checkout-caption">
          <h3>House and Land Packages</h3>

          <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-checkout btn-red" role="button">Check out Button</a> 
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You know what! You rock

Comment: Thanks and glad I could help.